# How can we take a short string from a long string in asp.net mvc3 using LINQ?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, string, linq

I am currently working on a small ecommerce project. I want to show a small description for a product instead of displaying all the description (comming from a database). 

Here is my controller;

```
var products = context.Products.OrderBy(p => p.ProductName);
@ViewBag.ProductList = products.ToList<Product>();
```

And here is my view code;

```
<ul class="display" id="content">
@foreach( var item in @ViewBag.ProductList as IEnumerable<Product>)
{
    @Html.Partial("_ProductPartial", item)
}
</ul>
```

Now inside my  Partial **"_ProductPartial"** view, i have that description field called;

```
<p>
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ProductDescription)
</p>
```

Now, i want to display a short description for a product (instead of displaying the whole description which is by default works). 

**So, How can i do this using LINQ?** 

**Is there any other way (if possible)?**

Comment: Your question is how to get a part of your string ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm doing this by using ViewModel :

```
    public string ProductDescription { get; set; }

    public string ShortDescription
    {
        get
        {
            var text = ProductDescription;
            if (text.Length > 21)
            {
                text = text.Remove(19);
                text += "..";
            }
            return text ;
        }
    }
```

For you if you don't want to make a ViewModel you could extend your Product class to have this read only property

Comment: My knowledge of ViewModels is limited, but wouldn't that require changes in the controller? Are there any negative sides in adding an extra layer between the controller and the view?

Comment: @ArmanBimatov The `ViewModel` is not an extra layer between your Controller and Views. The Views in MVC are strongly typed so instead of make them strongly typed to Model you'll strongly typed to ViewModel